# Why does \typearea affect page/paper size?

Tags: koma-script, paper-size

I'd like to use the \typearea package in order to properly calculate the size of the text block. However, invoking the package sets the paper size at A4, and I want to use a smaller size. Here's a MWE, commenting out the \usepackage...{typearea} line results in the correct paper size.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12.5pt,headsepline]{book} 

\usepackage[paperheight=7in,paperwidth=4.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}



\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Georgia}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}


\usepackage[fontsize=12.5]{scrextend}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}

\usepackage{scrextend}

%\usepackage[BCOR=10mm,DIV=calc,pagesize]{typearea}

\usepackage{anyfontsize}


\title{Page Size Problem}
\date{}


\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter title}
\section{Section title}
\kant[1-15]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't load packages twice (e.g. **scrextend**). The options you are passing `book` have no effect.

Comment: @cfr: how true. An artifact of creating a MWE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to use both packages `geometry` and `typearea` to set the page layout.

Package `typearea` knows an option to set the paper size: `paper=<width>:<height>`. So you could use

```
\usepackage[pagesize,paper=4.25in:7in,BCOR=10mm,DIV=calc]{typearea}
```

But note that your fontsize is to large for this small paper.

Comment: You're absolutely right about the font size. The pdfinfo CL program doesn't exist on OSX, so I didn't realize that all along I was looking at a4. I'll try to get an intermediate size, maybe 10.5. The paper size is more or less the same as for mass market paperbacks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the packages geometry and typearea in the same document. There is currently (Jan. 2016) a beta of the komascript bundle which includes a kind of coexistence, but you probably do not use the beta, do you?

If you describe what you whish to do, maybe there is another solution. By the way, why are you using book as a documentclass and scrextend-package, instead of scrbook?

Comment: No, I am not using a beta of the komascript bundle. I am trying to obtain a properly-calculated text block. I like the defaults of the bookest class. If I knew how to replicate them with scrbook, I would.